# Merge divs with same value from angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to make a Calendar of my own

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1kfbod?file=src/app/app.component.css

This is a full example of my component.
How can I merge the week divs that have the same value `{{day.weekNumber}}` (one div instead of 4 for the example below)?

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to merge the divs that have the same {{day.weekNumber}}?...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Not a link to an offsite resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you should have separate array for your week numbers.

**Typescript**

```
 public weekNumbers: number[] = [];
 public rowWidth: any = 100 + '%';
 ngOnInit() {
    ...
    ...  // your existing code
    ...
    let weeks = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.numberOfDaysCurrentMonth; i++) {
      this.daysToDisplayInCurrentMonth[i - 1] = new Date(this.currentYear, this.currentMonth - 1, i).getDay();
      const day = {
        number: i,
        weekDay: new Date(this.currentYear, this.currentMonth - 1, i).getDay(),
        name: this.dayNames[this.daysToDisplayInCurrentMonth[i - 1]],
        weekNumber: this.getWeekNumber(new Date(this.currentYear, this.currentMonth - 1, i))
      };

      weeks.push(day.weekNumber);
      this.days.push(day); 
    }

    this.weekNumbers = [];
    weeks.forEach((ele) => {
      if(this.weekNumbers.indexOf(ele) < 0) {
        this.weekNumbers.push(ele);
      }
    });
    this.rowWidth = (100/this.weekNumbers.length) + '%';
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row-calendar">
        <div class="week-number" [style.width]="rowWidth" *ngFor="let week of weekNumbers">
            <label class="number-label"><span>{{week}} </span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, exactly what I needed!